# Performance of Triplet loss network vs multiclass classification

Tags: classification

I am training a triplet loss based classification network and a normal multiclass classification network on some image data. In my case, the triplet loss network performs worse than the multiclass network. I have tried changing layers, neurons, margin, etc. for the triplet loss network, but the multiclass network still performs better. Are there any cases where the triplet loss network can perform worse than normal multiclass classification? If no, what are the possible things I can look at to improve or change in the triplet loss network for it to work?

It is 5 class classification with some given features.

Comment: Triplet loss is not normally used directly for fixed classification tasks, it is more for things like identity recognition (where there are changing, unknown or large numbers of target classs). Could you give more details (use [edit]) about the task where you are comparing the two approaches?

Answer (score 0):

For me triplet loss function (as mentioned by [Neil Slater](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/836/neil-slater) as well), is used for object recognition i.e. identify the similar object. Face-recognition is one of the use case.

> This function is based upon [Siamese Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siamese_neural_network), which will provide
>   us the feature vector as an output. During recognition, we compare the
>   feature-vector of the new image with the feature-vector of the
>   training data. Select the one which has closer matching.

In order to improve Triplet-loss function, you can try **different similarity approaches** or **different threshold value's**. Please do share the output.

But again for me it's not comparable with object-classification use case.

Comment: I do the same. I used the output of triplet lambda normalization as the input for Attention layer and output of Attention layer as input for Classification. The model learnt Tripplet very fast and correctly while classification is slower but also gain more accuracy. Will share codes sometime.

Comment: Sure. Please do share the code.